# Refresh combobox when navigate on datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Please help!

I did many research on the internet, but didn't find any solution for my question.

I have a form with foods. There is a grid on the form and with it I can navigate on the food table. There is a combobox on the screen (not in the grid) which contains the categories. The combobox is filled up with the categories from categories table. When I change the record on the datagrid every field updated on the form except the combobox.

- [first record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTcJX.jpg)
- [second record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CH0dB.jpg)

So my question is: what I have to do to refresh the combobox, to show the saved category when I navigate on the grid?
In the category table the category has "id" field and in the food table there is a "categoryid" field.

I have this in the xaml file:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="categoryComboBox" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3,4,20,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource categoryViewSource}}"
                  SelectedValuePath="CategoryId"
                  DisplayMemberPath="CatName"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding CategoryId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Hi, you should refresh your combo box SourceItems collection each time you select the new DataGrid row. This collection should be bound to some ObservableCollection within the ComboBox DataContext. So you should clear and re-fill that collection.

Comment: The combo itemsource is ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource categoryViewSource}}". The items doesn't change (add/remove) in the combobox during the navigation. Just Should show the relevant value. For example: the combobox items at the moment "First category", "Second category". When the cursor on the first record int the datagrid the combo should shoes "First Category" if the cursor on the second record the combo should shows "Second category".

Comment: Then you should update the selected combo item( i mean its DataContext bound property), in this way the combo selected item should be boun with the next UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged and Mode=TwoWay. If it won't be helpful try to re-render the combo-box. You can trigger the rendering if you change te size of combo(its width or height). So, if you'll scale In/Out(like zoom in or out) your combo it will be re-rendered.

Comment: Hi Ilan, I added my code form the xaml file to my question. I inserted into it your suggestion.  Didn't help. I resized the combobox like this : categoryComboBox.Width = categoryComboBox.Width + 1; categoryComboBox.Width = categoryComboBox.Width - 1;   Do I do something wrong? Please have a look.

Comment: please see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see you have a small error in your code. I should use the SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem. So change it and I think it will work properly. And in addition You don't need any workaround with the scaling as I suggested before.
Here is example:

**XAML**

```
     <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
        <ComboBox x:Name="categoryComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource categoryViewSource}}"
              SelectedValuePath="CategoryId"
              DisplayMemberPath="CatName"
              SelectedValue="{Binding CategoryId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ComboBox>
        <Button Content="Change Category" Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

**DataContext**

```
public class MyComboDataContext:BaseObservableObject
{
    private int _categoryId;
    private ICommand _selectionChangedCommand;

    public MyComboDataContext()
    {
        CategoryId = 1;
    }

    public int CategoryId
    {
        get { return _categoryId; }
        set
        {
            _categoryId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public ICommand SelectionChangedCommand
    {
        get { return _selectionChangedCommand ?? (_selectionChangedCommand = new RelayCommand(SelectionChanger)); }
    }

    private void SelectionChanger()
    {
        CategoryId += 1;
        if (CategoryId == 4)
            CategoryId = 1;
    }
}
```

**Explanations:**

**First of all, this is an example that is *simulating* the update of a combo.** Here the combobox selected value is changed on each button click. In your example the category selection should effect the combo selected value. So each time the grid category selection happens you should push selected category id into the property the combo SelectedValue is bound to it.

**In order to help you please update your question with next things:**

1. Are there any Binding expression errors in your output window?
2. How do you handle a DataGrid selection in your code.
3. How the data grid selection effects the combobox SelectedValue(it have to be selected value)?

Let me know if you need more help. And feel free to mark you question as answered if my answer was helpful.

Comment: Thank you Ilan for your very good help. I will try it at the evening. Just a little bit confused, on the datagrid there is no category combobox to select category. The grid shows the food table and just contains which category belongs to. On the grid the cursor moving on the food table and I just want to show the right name of the category in the category combobox. Please see the pictures. The first record in the datagrid has no category id (accidentally).

Comment: Hi Ilan, unfortunately your code didn't help. We are not in the same boat. Probably my explanation not to good. I think my problem is simplier. I have tried in C# form it is working fine. But WPF I cannot do it. I try to explain again: There is a form which maintains the food table. On the food table I can move with the datagrid. When I select another record every field on the form updating except the combobox.The combobox just display the first category only.My expectation is when I select another record on the grid the combo displays the relevant category. Please see the pictures.Many thanks

Comment: @Zoltan Dear Zoltan, you have at least one error in your code. You have to be bound to the SelectedValue propert(since you get the data by the SelectedValuePath combo property). All other things are the binding issues, you should manage the binding in a correct way. I'll add questions try to answer them.

Comment: Hi Ilan, Thank you for the hint. I checked the output window and there was an error with binding. I rebinded the combobox and it is working fine now. `ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource categoryViewSource}}"
                      DataContext="{Binding Category, Source={StaticResource tADatabaseDataSet}}" 
                      SelectedValue="{Binding CategoryId, Source={StaticResource foodViewSource}}"
                      SelectedValuePath="Id"
                      DisplayMemberPath="CatName"`
and now is OK. Sorry for the format. I didn't learn the formatting yet

Comment: But I got an another issue. If you don't mind, I tell you. When the form is loaded the Category combo doesn't show anything, but the items are in the combo. So far was ok because I used this `categoryViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();`. But now this is not right because not sure the first category is selected for the first food record. So if I saved the 3rd category in the first food record and next time I launch the form the combo automatically shows the 3rd category.  Probably I can set the category in the combo with code. Is there any way to do with binding? Many thanks. Zoltan

Comment: @Zoltan it is a little bit heavy to understand the real flow since I don't have your code. First of all, the combo and the datagrid should have the same DataContext, then each time you select a new DataGrid row, the selected item property of date grid will be updated with a new value(bind to that property and you will always get the updated row data in your data context), so when the selection is happens you should update the combo selected value with the category Id of your row selected data.  Look at the button click(from my example) like it is a data grid selection event.

Comment: Hi Ilan, since I fixed the binding issue, as I mentioned above, the combo is updating automatically without any code. So the main issue is solved. :) But when the form launch there is no click on the grid and the combo is empty. I could fix this, I have written a little code which find the categoryId and I set selectedvalue in the combobox. And this works fine. But I belive there is a better way (binding) to do this automatically. Do you have any idea?

Comment: try to do it via DataGrid.SelectedIndex, set there some default value. It means that on a window loading moment there will be a default selected row that will start the selection in the combo.

Comment: Thank you Ilan for all your help. I think we can close this question now. It was good to work with you.